# Transaction rollback when exception in Spring

Tags: java, spring, transactions, commit, rollback

I am learning Spring and I have some troubles with transaction in Spring.

Here is my code

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void createGroupStudent(Student A,Student B,String nameGroup){
    try{
        //create Group
        createGroup(nameGroup);
        //createMember
        createMember(A,B);
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void createGroup(String nameGroup){
    try{
        repoGroup.save(nameGroup);
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void createMember(Student A,Student B){
    try{
        // function will throw a kind of Exception involve to " error constraint sql oracle " . 
        //It's my intended
        repoMember.save(A,B);
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The problem is when function `createMember()` throws Exception, transaction alway rollback why? I can't understand what happened! I added try, catch in each method but it didn't work.

Although method `createMember()` have trouble while saving to Database (Here i'm using function `saveAndFlush()`).I know it and I catch that exception. Parent transaction `createGroupStudent()` thinks itself is no problems and commit transaction . But when commit once again method `createMember()` will break and throw Exception.I think method `createGroup()` won't rollback. But in real, that function rollbacked,all of transactions were rollback? What happened?.

I'm using atomikos transaction.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

If any of the methods throws `Exception`, the transaction will rollback. But none of the methods are throwing `Exception`. Rethrow the `Exception` in catch block, it will work.Check the documentation for [Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#rollbackFor--) annotation.

Comment: Thanks . But when i catch any exceptions. Transaction still rollback ? I don't understand @.@ .

Comment: How did you check if the transaction is rolledback? It could be that  the transaction is not committed. Check your configuration.

Comment: I think , althought method createMember() have trouble when save to Database ( Here i'm using function ' saveAndFlush() ' ) . I know it and i catch that exception . Prarent transaction createGroupStudent() think itself is no problems and commit transaction . But when commit once again method createMember() will break and throw Exception . I think method createGroup() won't rollback. But in real, that function was rollback,all of transactions were rollback ? What's happened ???? .  It's my problems :( . I'm using atomikos transaction

Comment: What is the exception you are getting? Can you set 'Propagation' to 'Required', and try? https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#propagation--

Answer (score 1):

If you're using hibernate, think of this scenario.

When repoMember.save(A,B); is executed, hibernate session hasn't flushed the session (i.e., executes save sql) util createMember() is finished. When hibernate actually flushes and executes the save sql, that error occurs. That's why you might not able to catch that exception which causes your transaction rollback.

here is link that might be helpful
http://hedleyproctor.com/2014/08/understanding-hibernate-session-flushing/