# catch cause of UnexpectedRollbackException

Tags: java, rollback, jta

How can catch the cause of `rollback exception` when run the code below (here reason is unique constraint error ), I'm using `Weblogic`, `Spring`, `Hibernate`, `JTA`

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" order="200" />
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
</bean>


@Service
public class OrderService extend BaseService<Order, Long>   {


@Transactional 
 public Long  save(Order modelEntity)  {
    try{
         super.save(modelEntity);
 }
 catch(Exception exp){
    ....
  }

 }
}
------------------------------
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test/core/Order")
public class OrderController extends BaseController{

@Autowired(required = true)
private IOrderService iOrderService;



@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Long save(@RequestBody Order  modelEntity) {

    return iOrderService.save(modelEntity); 
 }
}

@Controller
public class BaseController {
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> handleUncaughtException(Exception ex,    WebRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String logMessage = ex.toString() + " " + ex.getMessage();

    if (ex.getCause()!= null) {
        logMessage += ex.getCause().toString() + " " +   ex.getCause().getMessage();

    }
 return new ResponseEntity<String>(" ", responseHeaders,    HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQoon.png)

> [ERROR] org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: setRollbackOnly called on transactionweblogic.transaction.RollbackException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction setRollbackOnly called on transactionorg.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction

Comment: did u try `try catch`??

Comment: yes ,but the problem is when save method is called, hibernate return unique constraint exception when saving to Database but because the method is transnational UnexpectedRollbackException occurred.
but i want to  catch the cause of RollbackException  that here is unique constraint exception

Comment: So catch it in `try catch`

Comment: @Transactional 
public Long  Save(Order modelEntity)  {
try{
    return super.save(modelEntity);

}

Comment: and `catch (UniqueConstraintException e)` and what is the problem?

Comment: when  using hibernate,  the scenario is

When  save( ); is executed, hibernate session hasn't flushed the session (i.e., executes save sql) util super.save() is finished. When hibernate actually flushes and executes the save sql, that error occurs. 

i wont to catch that exception which causes  transaction rollback.

Comment: I must say that i dont understand what you are trying to achieve here. You want to catch particular exception but you dont want to catch it at the same time. Anyway, you can catch it like I told you and rethrow as well. I might have misunderstood your description at some point as well.

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759599/transaction-rollback-when-exception-in-spring

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html
Both spring and jta apic contains `noRollbacOn` property where u can specify to not to rollback on particular exception and catch it outside of transactional scope.

Comment: You should rather edit your post and attach given code as nobody will read this mess you created in the comments.

Comment: according to the code above we expect to catch exception in BaseController but cached exception is UnexpectedRollbackException and cause of exception is not uniqeConstraint error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007097/unexpectedrollbackexception-a-full-scenario-analysis

Comment: for getting the root cause of an UnexpectedRollbackException you can use exception.getRootCause() or exception.getMostSpecificCause() to catch the underlying exceptions.