# Spring boot, Transactional annotation not working on Service, SimpleJPA repository Transactional partially deleting

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

1. Calling JPArepository to deleteAllById [Debug Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNTpV.png) Internally using hibernate Provider for JPA

Implementation Class SimpleJpaRepository has Transactional Annotation at the top

2. Due to Transactional Annotation it went into Proxy [Debug Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9ugA.png)
3. In loop it is deleting in bulk, Deleting one by one in debug mode, when 1 element is deleted checking in database, element still Exist, but then post 1 element deletion forcefully throwing exception, then 1 delete is being committed in database (Any configuration missing here)? see there is some option of Transactional(rollback = "Exception.class"), but how to add it in SimpleJPARepository class ?
   [Debug Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjwdU.png)
4. Main issue, I am putting Transactional annotation at top of service method called by rest API, which is internally calling multiple other services which are actual doing JPA transaction like update/delete/create (So transactional annotation on top of my service is not going in Proxy as per step 2 debug (But internal JPA calls going into Proxy), checked many things, public method...) still nothing worked

**StartupClass Configuration Annotation**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:spring/starter.xml")
@PropertySource("classpath:config/${env}/application.properties")
@EnableJpaAuditing()
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
```

**Transaction Manager Main**

```
@Bean()
@Primary
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Comment: Try flushing the transaction, check this example [1].

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759599/transaction-rollback-when-exception-in-spring